# Is the data below sufficient to arrive at a solution?

Tags: number-theory

Try to find the factors of a number given the following data. Best illustrated with an example. Lets take a number say $77=11\times 7$. You are given the following numbers. $12, 65, 89, 142, 166$, etc. The numbers form a pattern. $12 = 7\times 2 - 2$, or $12=11+1$. $65 = 7\times 9 + 2$, or $65=11\times 6 -1$. $89 = 7\times 13 -2$, or $89=11\times 8 +1$ and so on. If we add any two successive numbers and find their greatest common divisor, we end up with $77$. The question is if we can use this information to somehow manipulate the numbers and find the factors of $77$. I am looking for a generalized solution that will work for any semi prime.

Comment: You seem to see a pattern where there is none. This series could have started with 13 and go like 13, 64, 90, 141, 167... It could have started with 14. It could have started with ***any*** number. It has nothing to do with the factorization of 77. Then again, maybe you are telling us only a half of the story.

Comment: That is to say, you have a sequence $a_1,a_2,\dots$ where for each $i$, $a_i+a_{i+1}$ is a multiple of 77. There are many such sequences, I don't see anything special about yours, nor any way to use it to factor 77.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Well,yes I did not choose the numbers randomly.The starting number 12 = 11x + 1 or 7y -2 and x+y = 3.(1+2). Also, (11+7)/(x+y) = 6. In this case 11, 12,13 and 14 satisfy the given condition. Lets take a larger example. 8051(83 × 97). and the following sequence starting with 1341,6710,9392..... 1341 = 83x + 16 = 97y +14. Also x+y = 30 = 16+14 . Also,180/(16+14) =6. @GerryMyerson

Comment: It's a lot of playing with numbers, but what makes you think it's of any use for factorization?

Comment: I don't. All I want to know is if the equation a.x + p = 1341 and b.y - q =1341      where p+q = x+y and (a+b)/(x+y) =6 can be solved efficiently. a.b = 8051. I mean is there a general way to solve these equations?

Comment: What do you mean by "solve these equations"? You have written five equations involving six letters. Are you asking to solve these five equations in six unknowns?

Comment: For integer solutions.@GerryMyerson

Comment: I know you are looking for integer solutions, I just don't know which letters represent given quantities and which ones you want to solve for.

Comment: @GerryMyerson All the letters are unknown. They are all variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you succeed, the internet cryptography will be in danger. also you will solve the integer factorization problem (and all its equivalents). no matter how you accumulated the data, if it works for any semi prime (it can be generalized to factorize any number). which is unlikely since the best of the best of the mathematicians worked on this problem or something similar and the best result is a sub-exponential accumulating data algorithm to factor semi primes number.

its very hard problem, i don't want to disappoint you but i think a conclusion whether this problem is solvable in polynomial time or not will need at least few decades from now.

note : for the question you asked in the comments . these are the only integer solutions.

$(a=-97\land b=-83\land p=-17\land q=-13\land x=-14\land y=-16)\lor (a=-1\land
   b=-8051\land p=-1\land q=-1341\land x=-1342\land y=0)\lor (a=83\land b=97\land
   p=13\land q=17\land x=16\land y=14)\lor (a=8051\land b=1\land p=1341\land
   q=1\land x=0\land y=1342)$

Comment: Right these equations can't be solved in polynomial time because to solve them one needs to factor N. I was just wondering if there was an alternative way to solve them